# how to use different maps for mobility models?

Tags: omnet++

I want to use different maps (for example map of an urban area like in manhattan mobility model) in my simulations. Is it possible to do it in my omnetpp.ini file as some initialization?
I use the mobility module in inet framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- OMNeT++ 4.6 does not contain any support for showing maps except displaying a background image in the module, but that must be carefully aligned to match your mobility model.
- OMNeT++ 5.0 will support osgEarth to display 3D models + display maps. You may experiment with the 5.0 Technical Preview (available in the test folder) [Download](https://omnetpp.org/component/jdownloads/category/31-release-test-versions?Itemid=-1). Note that this is Linux only for the moment, and you still have to implement your visualization if you want to use it in INET. Check the **osg-earth** example in the samples folder.

Comment: thanks for your answer! is it possible to add extra limits to how the mobile nodes move? Currently, mobile nodes move based on X, Y and Z axis limitations. It gives out a rectangular shape in 2D space. Is it possible to have more complex area like a thing that models streets of an urban area?

Comment: Of course. Mobile nodes move according to their mobility model. You can implement whatever movement you you want or use the currently available models if they fit your needs. I suggest to take a look at RectangleMobility (for simple cases) or you can program any path using the TurtleMobility model. PLUS: If you receive an acceptable answer on StackOverflow, ples ACCEPT it. It helps the community to find the right answers and rewards the people answering the questions.